# UserCreationForm Django 4.0 não exibe o default

Tags: django

Estou criando um blog simples e quero fazer uma página de login para novos usuários, para isso eu usei o modelo default da classe UserCreationForm. O problema é que quando acesso para registar o novo usuário aparece apenas o botão, mas as informações da classe não.

## Código

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


# Create your views here.
def logout_view(request):
    """Faz logout do usuario"""
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))

def register(request):
    """Faz cadastro de novo usuario"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # exibe o formulario de cadastro em branco
        form =  UserCreationForm()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()

            #Faz login do usuário e o redireciona para a página inicial
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                    password = request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

### HTML

```html
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
    
{% block content %}
    
<form method="post" action="{% url 'users:register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">register</button> 
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}" />

</form>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

### Saída esperada

[image: Saída esperada]

### Saída que recebo

[image: Saída que recebo]

PS: Imagino que o problema esteja na **views.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, existe dois problemas de lógica na implementação do seu código.

O primeiro está nesta chamada:

```
context = {'form': form}
```

Em seu código a variável `form` não está definida, pois não foi declarada no escopo do método `register`.

A outra coisa é a maneira como está fazendo a chamada `form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)` que poderia ser simplificada por:

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
```

Sabendo destas informações, para resolver o problema basta fazer os ajustes sugeridos:

```
def register(request):
    """Faz cadastro de novo usuario"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # exibe o formulario de cadastro em branco
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form', UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()

            #Faz login do usuário e o redireciona para a página inicial
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                password = request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

O código acima resolve o problema aproveitando a sua implementação para resolver os problemas com poucas mudanças.

Para melhorar a manutenção eu sugiro fazer uma implementação da seguinte forma:

```
def register(request):
    """Faz cadastro de novo usuario"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return create(request)
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form', UserCreationForm()})

def create(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

    new_user = form.save()

    #Faz login do usuário e o redireciona para a página inicial
    authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
        password = request.POST['password1'])
    login(request, authenticated_user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))
```

Desta forma estamos implementando um código melhor estruturado e mais fácil de entender e consequentemente mais fácil da fazer manutenção, pois a separação de responsabilidades ficou bem definida e auto-contida dentro de cada método.

Comment: Por que a variável form não foi definida no escopo se ela aparece no primeiro if?

Comment: Porque ela está indentada em um nível diferente. @HenriqueFH